# Runtime analysis of dependent nested for

Tags: algorithm, runtime, analysis

0

Here is the algorithm:

```
int sum = 0
for (int i = 2N; i > 0; i = i / 4) 
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j+=2) 
    sum++
  end for
end for
```

I figured this would be linearithmic, but it's just linear. I would appreciate seeing a formalized summation and not a qualitative explanation. I have tried doing this but I fail to get linear runtime.

Answer (score 2):

At the first external iteration you increment sum about **N** times, at the second - about **N / 4** times, then about **N / 16** times, etc. So the total number will be around **N + N / 4 + N / 16 + N / 64 + ...** which is an equivalent of **4N / 3**.

You can easily prove it in a more formal way, but it would be off-topic for SO community. Therefore you complexity is just linear.

Answer (score 1):

Cut it in pieces:

```
int sum = 0
```

Here you have O(1).

```
for (int i = 2N; i > 0; i = i / 4)
```

How many times will this run? Let's say it will run k times and evaluate k:

2N / 4^k = 1 => 2N = 4^k => k = log4(2N). To simplify, let's just call k = lg(N).

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j+=2) 
    sum++
end for
```

In the first case, this for goes until N, then N/4, then N/16, etc.

What this gives you is:

∑(N / 4^i), i = 0 ... k =

N * ∑ 1/4^i, i = 0 ... k

∑ 1/4^i, i = 0 ... k is a series that is smaller than [4/3](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2B+1%2F4+%2B+1%2F16+%2B+...), since it stops in k = lg(n) because the outer loop just runs lg(n) times.

Hence, the complexity is O(X < 4/3 * N), therefore, linear.

Answer (score 1):

Since you requested a formalized summation *only*; please note that the number of operations of your algorithm can be *modeled* by the series:

                                                                         
[image]

Which converges to: 
                                        [image]

(*This can be validated by using the geometric series test*).

So your algorithm's *time complexity* is O(**N**).